# Why is this ruby method not terminating at return?

Tags: ruby, recursion

newbie ruby question

code challenge: string collapse: remove all adjacent duplicates in a given string. Note: removal of adjacent duplicates can create new adjacent duplicates, you must remove these as well.

I'm pretty sure I solved this with simple recursion but when I walk through this step by step in a debugger the code doesn't terminate when it reaches the return line and begins adding then removing letters to the string until finally terminating.

for example

```
         zzzxaaxy => zxaaxy => zxxy => zy => zxxy => zy => zxxy => 
                                       ^ code hits return line here and should stop but instead continues
```

```
def same_char_collapse(str)
    ar = str.split('')
    ar.map.each_with_index do |char1, idx|
        char2 = ar[idx+1]
        if char1 == char2
            ar.delete_at(idx)
            ar.delete_at(idx)
            same_char_collapse(ar.join(''))
        end
    end
    return ar.join('')
end
```

Comment: Your recursive step takes `ar.join('')` (i.e. a brand new string) as an argument and ignores what `same_char_collapse` returns so your recursion doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Instead of lots of `delete_at` calls you may want to use `select` to filter.

Comment: Nutshell: it is, but only the current call. Recursion is often best understood with a well-known example (like fib) and a pencil and paper: trace it out.

Answer (score 0):

The return keyword does not mean "terminate instantly and return my value", it means "return to the method that called me."

So when you call your method and it returns "zxxy" instead of "zy", it is because it is just returning the result of ar.join() in the first call to same_char_collapse.

```
def same_char_collapse(str)
    ar = str.split('')
    ar.map.each_with_index do |char1, idx|
        char2 = ar[idx+1]
        if char1 == char2
            ar.delete_at(idx)
            ar.delete_at(idx)
# same_char_collapse(ar.join('')) doesn't change the value we are returning.
# you could delete this line and the method would still return the same thing 'zxxy'
            same_char_collapse(ar.join(''))
        end
    end
# ar's value is zxxy from the loop since the same_char_collapse(ar.join('')) line
# doesn't change ar. only the ar.delete_at(idx) lines modified ar.
    return ar.join('') 
end

same_char_collapse('zzzxaaxy') # first call to same_char_collapse
```

Essentially, if you want to fix your solution, you should make sure you are using the value produced in the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help and after lots of trial and error I eventually worked 
 out a solution

```
def dupes?(word) 
    word.each_char.with_index do |char, idx|
        if char == word[idx+1]
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

def removeDupe(word)
    ar = word.split('')
    ar.map.with_index do |char,idx|
        if char == ar[idx+1]
            ar.delete_at(idx)
            ar.delete_at(idx)
        end
    end
    return ar.join('')
end

def same_char_collapse(str)
    if dupes?(str)
        same_char_collapse(removeDupe(str))
    else
        return str
    end
end
```